# Angular2: Shared component thats used for routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using a component for routing in 2 separate modules. Angular throws an error about 2 declarations. How can I make this shared?

Typical guides for shared components show how to share but not use in the module for routing.

I want to use the ProductComponent in 2 separate modules but the component is used for routing so typical shared component strategy doesn't work.

Routing :

EXAMPLE1.module.ts

`

```
...
import { ProductComponent } from '../../product/product.component';

export const routes:Routes = [
    { path: 'products/:product-slug',  component: ProductComponent },
    other example 1 routes
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        ProductComponent,
        other example 1 components
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
    ]
})
export class EXAMPLE1 { }
```

`

EXAMPLE2.module.ts

`

```
...
import { ProductComponent } from '../../product/product.component';

export const routes:Routes = [
    { path: 'different/:product-slug',  component: ProductComponent },
    other example 2 routes
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        ProductComponent,
        other example 2 components
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
    ]
})
export class EXAMPLE1 { }
```

`

The product component is shared amongst these 2 modules

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any more code you can share? your question is unclear.

Comment: @J.Pichardo updated above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can export that component in your shared.module.ts like this

```
declarations: [ ProductComponent,
               ...
              ]
exports: [ ProductComponent],
```

after that you can import your shared module in the 2 modules

```
imports:[ 
        SharedModule,
      ]
```

so in your app.routing.ts you can import it and you dont need to declare it in the modules anymore, import your component in your both routing files, something like this

```
import { ProductComponent } from '../shared/product.component.ts'
```

Comment: but if ProductComponent is used in routing it throws an error when using sharedmodule

Comment: you need to import your component in your routing files from shared folder , import { ProductComponent } from '../shared/product.component.ts'

Comment: thanks so that worked, adding import for shared to handle declaration and also importing the component for routing did it. I was trying to only do one or the other not both at the same time

Answer (score 0):

you cannot declare one component in two module.

You either declare it in one module and then export it and use it in the other module. or you create a new shared module and will be shared between both.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ProductComponent
    ],
    exports: [ProductComponent]
})
export class EXAMPLE1 { }

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        EXAMPLE1 
    ]
})
export class EXAMPLE2 { }
```

and now you can use the first component, with no problem I guess!

Comment: I know this, but using a sharedmodule still leaves the ProductComponent undeclared for routing in both modules...

Comment: Now I understand what you want. In that case, you need to use Lazy loading. This is a good article about how to use it: https://medium.com/@kouipheng.lee/lazy-loading-with-angular-4-29c23792b7f4 This will allow you to add routing from other modules to the main module.

Answer (score 0):

For that you would do a shared module, something like

```
@NgModule({
      declarations: [ ProductComponent ],
      exports:[ ProductsComponent ]
 })
 export class SharedProductModule{}
```

And then import that module in both modules

```
@NgModule({
     imports: [ SharedProductModule ]
 })
 exports class ExampleModule {}
```

Comment: so i tried that but it still gives an error saying 'cannot find ProductComponent' for the routing. Shared works if its not used in routing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fateh Mohamed I got it working

```
...
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module'; <-- for declerations
import { ProductComponent } from '../../product/product.component'; <-- for routing

export const routes:Routes = [
    { path: 'products/:product-slug',  component: ProductComponent },
    other example 1 routes
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SharedModule <----- add shared module
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        other example 1 components <-- remove declaration of component
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
    ]
})
export class EXAMPLE1 { }
```

Comment: If the answer from Fateh Mohamed works for you, then please mark it as the correct answer. Thank you!